# This release is compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

Tags: java

I'm trying to publish my native android app to the google play store and I'm getting this error:

> This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

and added this to app Gradle file:

```
ndk {abiFilters  "x86", "armeabi-v7a", "x86_64", "arm64-v8a"}
```

My app is a very simple app that's why I am not using lib.
and I am using an android studio with java.

Comment: hi @shahin Are you able to fix this?